# Excel - Find first / last time from list of datetime fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Forgive me if this is an easy question, but my online searches didn't produce anything that worked in my dataset.

I have a long list of timestamps in column A, for example :

```
03/17/2020 01:26:16 PM
03/17/2020 03:55:46 PM
03/18/2020 08:56:13 AM
03/18/2020 09:25:53 AM
03/18/2020 10:46:47 AM
```

I need to find the earliest and latest time for each day.

Output would be in the format of :

```
A          | B           | C
03/17/2020 | 01:26:16 PM | 03:55:46 PM
03/18/2020 | 08:56:13 AM | 10:46:47 AM
```

As a bit of background, I am creating this spreadsheet in python's openpyxl.  I can do this in Python, but I need these values to be updated if the user updates the column A of datetimes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Pivot Table:

Pu the Days in rows and in the Date in values twice, then change one to the max and the other to the min.

Then format it the way you want:

[image]

Comment: That is how we traditionally did it.  But, the aim of this project is to make things as automated as possible.  OpenPYXL, what I'm using to create the worksheet, doesn't allow creation of pivot tables.